# The resource is locked Cannot access the data plane because of a read lock on the resource or its parent

Tags: azure, azure-storage

Team,
Using Azure Pass - Sponsorship subscription i have created storage account.
Now after creating it when i go to Access keys tab i am getting below error.

> Resource details:
>
> Performance/Access tier:Standard/Hot
>
> Replication:Read-access geo-redundant storage (RA-GRS) Account
>
> kind:StorageV2 (general purpose v2)

Error message:

> Access blocked
>
> The resource is locked
>
> Cannot access the data plane because of a read lock on the resource or its parent.

There is no locks applied for this resource.

Is storage account not available for my subscription?

How to resolve this error?

Please let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may check if you have reached [spend limit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-spending-limit) in your Azure Pass - Sponsorship subscription. [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/916992/azure-storage-table-read-lock) is a similar issue.

> When your usage results in charges that exhaust your spending limit,
>   the services that you deployed are disabled for the rest of that
>   billing period.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume this means the lock is on the parent, so on the resource group. remove the lock there and try again.

Comment: Nope, resource group also dont' have any lock.

Comment: this would mean its a subscription level lock?